# Memory Mapped File в C# (Linux)

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, monodevelop

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой-нибудь простой пример использования Memory Mapped File на C#.
(Как вариант, обмен состояниями потока между родительской программой и дочерним процессом)

Comment: Пайпы: [Named](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication), [Anonymous](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-anonymous-pipes-for-local-interprocess-communication).